# Especificarle el Autor a varios archivos a la vez

Tags: jscript

El siguiente JScript, escrito por @lxp para el explorador de archivos Directory Opus, en Windows 11 (64 bits), permite establecer o modificar el metadato "Autor" a algunos tipos de archivos, pero tiene el pequeño inconveniente de que solo permite modificar un archivo por vez ¿Alguien podría ayudarme para poder modificar varios archivos a la vez?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function OnClick(clickData) {
    var cmd = clickData.func.command;
    var tab = clickData.func.sourcetab;
    cmd.deselect = false;

    if (!tab.selected_files) return;

    var item = tab.selected_files(0);

    cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr' +
        ' FILE="' + item + '"' +
        ' META "author:{dlgstring|Autor:|' + item.metadata.doc.author + '}"');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tras mucha investigación conseguí la solución con estas tres simples líneas:

```
    if (tab.selected_files.count >= 2) {
        cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "author:{dlgstring|Autor:}"');

    } else {
```

**CÓDIGO RESULTANTE**

```
function OnClick(clickData) {
    var cmd = clickData.func.command;
    var tab = clickData.func.sourcetab;
    cmd.deselect = false;

    if (!tab.selected_files) return;

    if (tab.selected_files.count >= 2) {
        cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr META "author:{dlgstring|Autor:}"');

    } else {

        var item = tab.selected_files(0);

        cmd.RunCommand('SetAttr' +
            ' FILE="' + item + '"' +
            ' META "author:{dlgstring|Autor:|' + item.metadata.doc.author + '}"');
    }
}
```

Comment: lo raro es que no le estas pasando ningun parametro al primer comando.. como sabe a que cambiarlo, o siquiera a que archivos hacerlo?

Comment: @gbianchi no sé explicarte eso pues no sé nada de programación, el script fue escrito por otra persona y yo solo adicioné esas tres líneas después de estudiar otros scripts con condiciones. Lo cierto es que funciona perfecto, tanto cuando selecciono un archivo como cuando selecciono varios.

Comment: ok.. pero para mi, vas a tener algun otro efecto que no estas tomando en cuenta.. no lo estaras cambiando a todos por ejemplo?

Comment: @gbianchi el script funciona de la siguiente manera. Si selecciono un único archivo y este ya cuenta con algún autor especificado, este se me mostrará en la ventana, ahí tendré la oportunidad editarlo, ya sea adicionándole algún otro texto o eliminar completamente el autor. Si selecciono varios archivos, tengan o no autores previos, estos no se mostrarán en la ventana, si especifico algún texto, este se establecerá como Autor para todos los archivos (eliminándose cualquier autor previo), y si no especifico ningún texto, se eliminarán todos los autores.

Comment: Toda esa explicacion, en la respuesta...